# How can I unfollow the Weekend Pursuits channel?

Tags: apple-news

I'm exploring Apple News for the first time and confused about how its channels work. One of the channels appears to be missing its Remove button:

[image: Following Weekend Pursuits in Apple News]

1. Why is that channel different?
2. How do I remove it?